# Spring Security - Implementing UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I understand that Spring will pass the principal into controller's method if I include it as a method parameter.

I'm trying to extend this functionality by implementing `UserDetailsService`:

I created a class named `CustomUserDetails` that extends `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

I created a service named `CustomUserDetailsService` that implements `UserDetailsService`

**Exception**

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
>   cannot be cast to com.demo.model.CustomUserDetails

The following line in my controller method is throwing the exception:

```
CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) principal;
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayHomePage(ModelAndView modelAndView, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request) {

        // Throws exception here 
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) principal;      

        System.out.println(userDetails.getFirstName());

        // Tried this and it also throws exception
        // User cannot be cast to CustomUserDetails
        //Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        //CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();

        // Render template located at
        // src/main/resources/templates/dashboard.html
        modelAndView.setViewName("dashboard");

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Autowired
    SecurityHandler successHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/register*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/reset").permitAll().antMatchers("/forgot").permitAll().antMatchers("/grid").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard").successHandler(successHandler).usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/error**", "/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**");
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetails.java**

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

    public CustomUserDetails(String username, String password,
         Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {            
        super(username, password, authorities);
    }

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService.java**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException{         

        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(userName)) 
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User name is empty");

        //if you don't use authority based security, just add empty set
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(userName, "", authorities);            

        userDetails.setFirstName("Testing: " + new Date());


        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `Principal` you get is the `Authentication` object and not your user. On that you can call `getPrincipal` to get the actual user. (Which is also what the class cast exception is telling you).

Comment: can you post the code where the exception is actually being thrown?

Comment: @rptmat57 sure i added the controller method code

Comment: @M.Deinum tried that and still get a ClassCastException trying to cast User to CustomUserDetails....posted the controller code

Comment: No you are directly casting the `principal`. You should cut that to `Authentication` and then do `getPrincipal` on that.

Answer (score 0):

in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, you need add your register custom detail service:

`auth.userDetailsService(customDetailService)`

```
     @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to:

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayHomePage(ModelAndView modelAndView, Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {

    CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal;
```

Note it returns a Authentication object.